# Find Pixel Color using Texture2DMutable on Sprite from SpriteSheet

Tags: cocos2d-x, texture2d, render-to-texture

I am trying to find out the color of a pixel on a Sprite. Using the method at the following

```
CCImage *testImage = new CCImage;
testImage->initWithImageFile(filename);
unsigned char *data = testImage->getData();
```

Then I would use the data to create a Texture2DMutable. From there I was able to achieve what I want.

Now my project's assets are being packed using TexturePacker, into a sprite sheet. Now my sprites are created using `createWithSpriteFrameName`. I tried using the method from the following link:

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/get-raw-image-data-from-sprite-or-texture2d/3360/2

to get a Image from my Sprite object, but I believe the texture that was rendered was incorrect. Can anyone point me in a better direction please? I am currently working with cocos2d-x 3.2.